# Why does Evan say that Tess lied to him about the phone call?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, freaky-friday

In ***Freaky Friday***, In one scene, Tess rejects the phone ring in front of Evan.

> Evan: Are you gonna get that?
>
> Tess:No.
>
> Evan: Oh, so you don't answer your phone.I told you I wouldn't be able
>   to call you on your honeymoon, but **you lied to me. You're a liar!**
>
> Tess:I'll get it. (she referring to phone-ring here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If she previously indicated he would be able to reach her in a circumstance where people usually don't want to be reached (on her honeymoon), it would be an indication that she always answers incoming calls.  By not picking up a call in an ordinary, regular situation, that's a contra-indication of her earlier statement - she does not pick up in situations where people normally don't, in fact, she sometimes does not pick up in ordinary situations.